# editurl not passing the parameter

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
$.jgrid.useJSON = true;

$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#tOceanC_ds_list").jqGrid({

        // add by default to avoid webmethod parameter conflicts

        // add by default to avoid webmethod parameter conflicts

        url: "Default.aspx?cmd=select",

        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['BOQID', 'BOQType', 'Description', 'Quantity'],
        colModel:[
            { name: "BOQID", hidden: true, index: "BOQID", jsonmap: "BOQID",search:true,key:true,editable:true },
            { name: "BOQType", summaryTpl: "{0}", editable: true, searchoptions: {}, index: "BOQType", width: 200, align: "center", jsonmap: "BOQType", searchoptions: {}},
            //{ name: "Description", editable: true, index: "Description", width: 200, align: "center", jsonmap: "Description", search: true },


    { "editoptions": { dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { var ec = 'DatePicker1'; if (typeof (jQuery(el).datepicker) !== 'function') alert('JQDatePicker javascript not present on the page. Please, include jquery.jqDatePicker.min.js'); jQuery(el).datepicker(eval(ec + '_dpid')); }, 200); } }, "summaryTpl": "{0}", "editable": true, "edittype": "text", "searchoptions": { dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { var ec = 'DatePicker1'; if (typeof (jQuery(el).datepicker) !== 'function') alert('JQDatePicker javascript not present on the page. Please, include jquery.jqDatePicker.min.js'); jQuery(el).datepicker(eval(ec + '_dpid')); }, 200); } }, name: "Description", index: "Description" },
            { name: "Quantity", editable: true, index: "Quantity", width: 200, align: "center", jsonmap: "Quantity", search: true }
        ],
        viewrecords: true, scrollrows: false, postBackUrl: "__doPostBack('#tOceanC_ds_list','jqGridParams')",
        editDialogOptions: { editCaption: "Edit Dialog", resize: false, closeAfterEdit: true, processData: "Default.aspx", bSubmit: "Submit", bCancel: "Cancel Editing", modal: true, recreateForm: true, errorTextFormat: function (data) { return 'Error: ' + data.responseText } },
        addDialogOptions: { recreateForm: true, errorTextFormat: function (data) { return 'Error: ' + data.responseText } },
        delDialogOptions: { errorTextFormat: function (data) { return 'Error: ' + data.responseText } },
        searchDialogOptions: {left:300,top:400,resize:false},viewRowDetailsDialogOptions: {},jsonReader: { id: "BOQID" },
        rowNum: 10,
        height: "60%",
        rownumbers: true,
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rowList:[10,20,30,50,100],
        pager: jQuery("#OceanC_pager"),
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: false, 
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"List of Users",
        editurl: "Default.aspx",


        //serializeGridData: function (data) {
        //    return $.toJSON(data);
        //},
        jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, id: "0" }
    });

    jQuery("#tOceanC_ds_list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#OceanC_pager", { add: false, edit: true, del: true, search: true, view: true,reload:true}, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: false }, jQuery('#tOceanC_ds_list').getGridParam('editDialogOptions'), jQuery('#tOceanC_ds_list').getGridParam('addDialogOptions'), jQuery('#tOceanC_ds_list').getGridParam('delDialogOptions'), jQuery('#tOceanC_ds_list').getGridParam('searchDialogOptions'), jQuery('#tOceanC_ds_list').getGridParam('viewRowDetailsDialogOptions')).bindKeys()


});

function customPhoto(cellVal, options, rowObject){
    return "<img src='assets/img/" + cellVal + "' height='50' width='50' >";
}


</script>
```

The `editurl` don't pass the parameter to edit the data like oper, del, edit, add
I want `editurl` to pass these parameter to code behind when I `request.querystring["oper"]` it return the empty or r`equest.querystring["del"]` it return empty

I am using asp.net webform 3.5 framework